# The problems in the P class can be polynomially reduced to its complement and vica versa?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

I considered the Euler circle problem to decide this.
The polynomial reduction is:
I add a new vertex in the graph:

- If the degree of each vertex is even, then I connect all the vertices with this new vertex
- Otherwise, I only connect the vertices with an odd number of degrees to the new vertex
  Is this a correct reduction?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Are you looking for a reduction from the problem of deciding whether a graph contains an Eulerian cycle to its complement, or are you interested in knowing whether all problems in NP can be reduced to their respective complements?

Comment: I try to prove that every P problems can be reduced to its complements and the opposite direction is also true. For this purpose I used the Euler circuit problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does two languages being in P imply reduction to each other?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19427/does-two-languages-being-in-p-imply-reduction-to-each-other)

Comment: Please, before asking a question, make sure that you search if it, or something very similar, already exists on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is false. $\emptyset$ cannot be reduced to its complement $\Sigma^*$ (and vice-versa).

However, if you restrict yourself to languages $L$ such that $L \not\in \{ \emptyset, \Sigma^*\}$ then it is true that $L \le \overline{L}$. To see this let $n$ be any fixed element of $L$ and let $y$ be any fixed element of $\overline{L}$. Such elements exist by our choice of $L$.

The reduction is given by:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
y & \mbox{if } x \in L \\
n & \mbox{if } x \not\in L
\end{cases}.
$$
Notice that $f$ can be computed in polynomial time since $L \in \mathsf{P}$, which means that we can decide in polynomial time whether $x \in L$.